# how to compile libnet for python 2.7 on windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cygwin, libnet

I have python 2.7 on windows xp, I need libnet but it's not supported for python 2.7 . 
I tried to compile it using cygwin, as I don't use python on cygwin gnu and I could not compile it using mingw32, is there any way to install mingw32 in the gnu of cygwin. I read some about VC compile but I totally didn't understand. I need it for w3af framework[which need scapy [which need libnet - and python 2.7]]
trying to make w3af framework run on windows [because it is not supported anymore on win]

Comment: HI, I have downloaded Microsoft visual studio 2008, trying to compile using its compiler , and I am facing this H:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I@top_srcdir@/include -I../../WPdpack/Include -Ih:\w3af\Python2
7\include -Ih:\w3af\Python27\PC /Tc@srcdir@/dnet.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Relea
se\@srcdir@/dnet.obj
dnet.c
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '@srcdir@/dnet.c': No such file
 or directory
error: command '"H:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' fa
iled with exit status 2

Comment: I think it need WPdpack , i'll give it a shot and come back , where are you guys

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Install Python 2.5 and dnet module
   https://code.google.com/p/libdnet/downloads/detail?name=dnet-1.12.win32-py2.5.exe&can=2&q=
   You can do this on other machine.
2. Modify filename "dnet-1.12-py2.5.egg-info" to "dnet-1.12-py2.7.egg-info" located at c:\python25\lib\site-packages\
3. Open binary file of dnet: dnet.pyd located at c:\python25\lib\site-packages\ by Ultraedit or associated tool(I use winhex)
4. Find the string "python2.5.dll", for my experience, it addressed 0x00019cD1, change hex value from "35" to  "37", the string will become "python2.7.dll"
5. copy that modified file to same place for python2.7 folder (c:\python27\lib\site-packages)

It works on my machine: Windows8, Python2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I've created a GNU makefile to build it for MSVC. It's [here](https://gist.github.com/gvanem/7d10b3c9e519ad388721)
Tested with Python 2.7 only.